# I want to have a submenu with tabs in my angular app

Tags: angular

I am using this tutorial https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-on-push?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.html to accomplish my goal however since my tabs re not in the root component I am having some difficulties.

In my case I have a contract with some properties that I would like to be in tabs.

The url where I want to have the second menu looks like this.
/contract/19050001

I have some more component for the contract for exemple
/memo
/time

Here is visually how I want my menus to looks like.

[image: Image of menus]

My folder structure looks like this

```
-->Home
--> Contract
     -->time
     -->memo
      ....
    contract.component.css
    contract.component.html
    contract.component.ts
```

How can I change the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-tabs-on-push?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexample%2Fexample.component.html so that the tabs are not in the root / but in /contract/:contractId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

1. I have added the file contract-routing.module.ts to my project in my folder -->contract

Which looks like this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ContractApplianceProposalComponent } from './appliance-proposal/contract-appliance-proposal.component';
import { ContractAttachementsComponent } from './attachments/contract-attachements.component';
import { ContractComponentsComponent } from './components/contract-components.component';
import { ContractComponent } from './contract-layout.component';
import { ContractCustomerComponent } from './customer/contract-customer.component';
import { ContractDiagnosisComponent } from './diagnosis/contract-diagnosis.component';
import { ContractHistoryComponent } from './history/contract-history.component';
import { ContractInvoiceComponent } from './invoice/contract-invoice.component';
import { ContractMemoComponent } from './memo/contract-memo.component';
import { ContractQuoteComponent } from './quote/contract-quote.component';
import { ContractRepairComponent } from './repair/contract-repair.component';
import { ContractSearchComponent } from './search/contract-search.component';
import { ContractShippingComponent } from './shipping/contract-shipping.component';
import { ContractTimeComponent } from './time/contract-time.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: ContractComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'search', component: ContractSearchComponent },
      { path: 'memo', component: ContractMemoComponent },
      { path: 'time', component: ContractTimeComponent },
      { path: 'customer', component: ContractCustomerComponent },
      { path: 'diagnosis', component: ContractDiagnosisComponent },
      { path: 'quote', component: ContractQuoteComponent },
      { path: 'repair', component: ContractRepairComponent },
      { path: 'shipping', component: ContractShippingComponent },
      { path: 'invoice', component: ContractInvoiceComponent },
      { path: 'history', component: ContractHistoryComponent },
      { path: 'attachments', component: ContractAttachementsComponent },
      { path: 'components', component: ContractComponentsComponent },
      { path: 'appliance-proposal', component: ContractApplianceProposalComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ContractRoutingModule { }
```

Then I added this path to my routes

{ path: 'contract/:contractId', loadChildren: contractModule },

And imported the module like this

```
const contractModule = () => import('./contract/contract.module').then(x => x.ContractModule);
```